# unknown mutation type в Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, firebase, vuex, vuetify

При работе над моим учебным проектом , при создании нового товара , товар не выводится на страницу товаров , хотя отображается в базе данных как созданный . В консоле выводит ошибку unknown mutation type: createProduct. Не могу найти проблему. Я думаю она находитсяsrc / store / modules/ products.js или src/components/Products/NewProduct.vue

Ссылка на github
https://github.com/Mark-770/vueStore.git

```
products.js
   import * as fb from 'firebase'

class Product {
  constructor (title, vendor, color, material, price, description, ownerId, imageSrc = '', promo = false, id = null) {
    this.title = title
    this.vendor = vendor
    this.color = color
    this.material = material
    this.price = price
    this.description = description
    this.ownerId = ownerId
    this.imageSrc = imageSrc
    this.promo = promo
    this.id = id
  }
}

export default {
  state: {
    products: []
  },
  mutations: {},
  actions: {
    async createProduct ({commit, getters}, payload) {
      commit('clearError')
      commit('setLoading', true)
      try {
        const newProduct = new Product(
          payload.title,
          payload.vendor,
          payload.color,
          payload.material,
          payload.price,
          payload.description,
          getters.user.id,
          payload.imageSrc,
          payload.promo
        )

        const product = await fb.database().ref('products').push(newProduct)
        commit('setLoading', false)
        commit('createProduct', {
          ...newProduct,
          id: product.key
        })
      } catch (error) {
        commit('setError', error.message)
        commit('setLoading', false)
        throw error
      }
    }
  },
  getters: {
    products (state) {
      return state.products
    },
    promoProducts (state) {
      return state.products.filter(product => {
        return product.promo
      })
    },
    myProducts (state) {
      return state.products
    },
    productById (state) {
      return productId => {
        return state.products.find(product => product.id === productId)
      }
    }
  }
}

src/components/Products/NewProduct.vue
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-layout row>
            <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                <h1 class="text--secondary mb-3">Create New Product</h1>
                <v-form ref="form" v-model="valid" lazy-validation class="md-3">
                  <v-text-field
                    v-model="title"
                      name="title"
                      label="Tatle"
                      type="text"
                      :rules ="[v => !!v || 'Title is require']"
                      required
                    >
                    </v-text-field>
                    <v-text-field
                    v-model="vendor"
                    name="vendor"
                    label="Vendor Product"
                    type="text"
                    ></v-text-field>
                    <v-text-field
                    v-model="color"
                    name="color"
                    label="Color Product"
                    type="text"
                    ></v-text-field>
                    <v-text-field
                    v-model="material"
                    name="material"
                    label="Material Product"
                    type="text"
                    ></v-text-field>
                    <v-text-field
                    v-model="price"
                    name="price"
                    label="Price Product"
                    type="text"
                    :rules ="[v => !!v || 'Price is require']"
                    required
                    ></v-text-field>
                    <v-text-field
                    v-model="description"
                    name="description"
                    label="Description Product"
                    type="text"
                    multi-line
                    ></v-text-field>
                </v-form>
                <v-layout class="mb-4">
                  <v-flex xs12>
                    <v-btn class="warning">
                      Upload
                      <v-icon right dark>
                        cloud_download
                      </v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
                <v-layout >
                  <v-flex xs12>
                   <img src="" height="200px">
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
                <v-layout >
                  <v-flex xs12>
                    <v-switch
                      color="primary"
                      v-model="promo"
                      label="Add to Promo?"
                    ></v-switch>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
                <v-layout >
                  <v-flex xs12>
                   <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                   <v-btn
                   :loading="loading"
                   class="success"
                   :disabled="!valid || loading"
                   @click="createProduct"
                   >Create Product</v-btn>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      title: '',
      vendor: '',
      color: '',
      material: '',
      price: 0,
      description: '',
      promo: false,
      valid: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    loading () {
      return this.$store.getters.loading
    }
  },
  methods: {
    createProduct () {
      if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
        const product = {
          title: this.title,
          vendor: this.vendor,
          color: this.color,
          material: this.material,
          price: this.price,
          description: this.description,
          promo: this.promo,
          imageSrc: 'https://image.ibb.co/g6czu8/HP_Omen_17.jpg'
        }

        this.$store.dispatch('createProduct', product)
          .then(() => {
            this.$router.push('/list')
          })
          .catch(() => {})
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: смею предположить что модуль у вас называется `products`, тогда вызов должен выглядеть так: `dispatch('products/createProduct', product)`

Comment: к сожалению это не сработало

Comment: посмотрел более подробно код, обратил внимание на отсутствие параметра [`namespaced`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/modules.html#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%91%D0%BD) для модуля, не исключаю возможности что по этой причине не все работает так как должно

Comment: @Bald вопрос решился куда проще , не указана сама мутация . mutations: {
    createProduct (state, payload) {
      state.products.push(payload)
    }
  },

Comment: раз вопрос решился таким образом, то думаю его стоит удалить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mutations: { createProduct (state, payload) { state.products.push(payload) } }
```